# Can I just create a chat room like that?

Tags: support, chat

I was thinking about creating a chatroom for a specific game (For Honor) but I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do so.

We do have some rooms that are game-specific but usually for more popular games. My fear is that the room might not even be that active but I can't tell that for sure without actually testing it.

So can I just open a room for a specific game or shouldn't I do that.

Comment: There are other game-specific chat rooms like the Monster Hunter or Overwatch ones!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You are absolutely allowed to make it, I don't know how popular it will be, but you can surely create the chatroom and give it a try, worst case it's no success and the room freezes.